# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web3js

```
data(){
    return {
        tables:[]
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.getData()
},
methods:{
    getData(){
        var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
            address: '0x123456..',
            topics: ['0x12345...']
        }, function(error, result){
            if (!error)
                console.log(result);
        })
        .on("data", function(log){
            // this.tables return the error message typeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method
            this.tables = [...log]
        })
    }
}
```

In vue JS i can't access populate the this.tables for data what is the other way to do that?

Comment: what does  the `log` variable look like in `.on("data", function(log){` ? I assume it can't be spread with the spread operator like `[..log]` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: log is just a returned data i don't have problem with it but the problem is the 'this.tables" it seems i can't pass that there so even if i do console.log(this.tables) it returns undefined

Comment: what kind of data is `log`? is it a string or number?

Comment: it's object data type

Comment: if its an object, I don't think you can spread an object into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i figured it out now so the solutions is

```
const self = this
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
            address: '0x123456..',
            topics: ['0x12345...']
        }, function(error, result){
            if (!error)
                console.log(result);
        })
        .on("data", function(log){

            self.tables.push(log)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

'this.tables' here mean the tables of the callback function, 'this' in callback don't target to vue data.

try `this.getData(this.tables)` in mounted().

and `getData(tables)` in methods,

then the callback should be
`function(log, tables){ tables = [...log]}`

Comment: yeah it's seems so do you know the better approach? to populate the 'this.table' for data from 'log' ?

Comment: just a hint would be fine for me

Comment: @MilesSelim sorry i just edited it, i submited an incomplete answer

Comment: hello i tried your approach but still does not work the 'this.tables' is still empty but the 'tables' variable has been populated